# why is the desirable number not getting stored in C from the user input data

Tags: c, scanf

My goal is to use the property of `scanf()` function. I want to supress `':'` in the input to get the hours and minutes value into their respective variables `hours_var` and `minutes_var`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    int hours_var,minutes_var;
    printf("Whats the time??\n");
    scanf("%d*c%d",&hours_var,&minutes_var);
    printf("%d\n", hours_var);
    printf("%d\n",minutes_var);
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
Whats the time??
2:24
2
0
```

I wanted 24 in the `minutes_var` variable . What did I miss??

Comment: `*c` should be `%*c` to ignore a character.

Comment: ***Always*** check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Answer (score 1):

As [*@mch*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3684343/mch) [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77907218/why-is-the-desirable-number-not-getting-stored-in-c-from-the-user-input-data#comment137346981_77907218), you are missing the format specifying character `%` before `*c`. In full, the format string should be `"%d%*c%d"`.

Note that this will match (and discard) *any* character that is not consumed by the preceding `%d` specifier, so an input format such as `2t24` would work. You could instead match the `:` character explicitly, as in `%d:%d`.

As [*@Some programmer dude*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77907218/why-is-the-desirable-number-not-getting-stored-in-c-from-the-user-input-data#comment137347005_77907218), the return value of `scanf` should always be checked to ensure you are not working with indeterminate values, in the event that a short number of *conversions* occurs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int hours, minutes;

    printf("What is the time: ");

    if (2 != scanf("%d:%d", &hours, &minutes)) {
        fputs("Invalid format.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%d\n%d\n", hours, minutes);
}
```

```
What is the time: 2:24
2
24
```

```
What is the time: 2t24
Invalid format.
```

You might also consider instead reading an entire line with [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), and using [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) or parsing a date and time format with a function like POSIX [`strptime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html).

Comment: Note that an input like `2:    34` will be accepted; `%d` always skips leading white space.  There's nothing you can do about that with `scanf()` — so it is just something to be vaguely aware of.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is, as we see in the name, a *scanner*  and was written to consume large files of tabular data. You do not *suppress* the delimiter, you just inform the scanner what is such symbol. As in the example below, you can use `"%2d:%2d"` so `scanf` knows that the delimiter is `:` and 2 integer values of up to 2 digits each are expected.

RTFM: As pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77907218/why-is-the-desirable-number-not-getting-stored-in-c-from-the-user-input-data#comment137347005_77907218) by [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude), **ALWAYS** check the return value of the function. Since this is a scanner it can read from 0 to the total of items you asked for. And it will tell you how many in the returned value you did not test for. It can also return -1 for `EOF` or for some error...

Consider that, as scanners, to read nothing is not an error for these family of functions..

#### example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int hh;
    int mm;
    const char* line = "2:4";
    int         res  = sscanf(line, "%2d:%2d", &hh, &mm);
    printf("    function read %d items, hour is %02d, minute is %02d\n", res, hh,mm);
    return 0;
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77907218/why-is-the-desirable-number-not-getting-stored-in-c-from-the-user-input-data
```

#### output

```
    function read 2 items, hour is 02, minute is 04
```